# convert numpy array from object dtype to float

Tags: python, numpy

How do I convert the foll. numpy from object dtype to float:

```
array(['4,364,541', '2,330,200', '2,107,648', '1,525,711', '1,485,231',
       '1,257,500', '1,098,200', '1,065,106', '962,100', '920,200',
       '124,204', '122,320', '119,742', '116,627', '115,900', '108,400',
       '108,400', '108,000', '103,795', '102,900', '101,845', '100,900',
       '100,626'], dtype=object)
```

I tried `arr.astype(float)` but that does not work because of `,` in each string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way

```
np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.replace(',',''),1,1)(arr).astype(float)
```

`frompyfunc` returns an object dtype array, which is fine in  this case.  Often I've found that it is 2x faster than than a list comprehension, but here it times about the same as `@coldspeed's`:

```
np.array([v.replace(',', '') for v in arr], dtype=np.float32)
```

That may be because we are starting with an object dtype array.  Direct iteration on an object dtype is a bit slower than iteration on a list, but faster than iteration on a regular numpy array.  Like a list, the elements of the array are pointers to strings, and don't require the 'unboxing' that a string dtype array would.

(and 2 to 3 x faster than the `np.char` version).

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do it is remove every comma:

```
np.array([v.replace(',', '') for v in arr], dtype=np.float32)
```

If you have pandas, `to_numeric` is a good option. It gracefully handles any invalid values that may creep in post replacement.

```
pd.to_numeric([v.replace(',', '') for v in arr], errors='coerce',  downcast='float')
```

Both methods return a float array as output.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> ar
array(['4,364,541', '2,330,200', '2,107,648', '1,525,711', '1,485,231',
       '1,257,500', '1,098,200', '1,065,106', '962,100', '920,200',
       '124,204', '122,320', '119,742', '116,627', '115,900', '108,400',
       '108,400', '108,000', '103,795', '102,900', '101,845', '100,900',
       '100,626'], dtype=object)
```

You can use `filter` to remove all non-digit elements and create floats:

```
>>> np.array(list(map(float, (''.join(filter(lambda c: c.isdigit(), s)) for s in ar))))
array([4364541., 2330200., 2107648., 1525711., 1485231., 1257500.,
       1098200., 1065106.,  962100.,  920200.,  124204.,  122320.,
        119742.,  116627.,  115900.,  108400.,  108400.,  108000.,
        103795.,  102900.,  101845.,  100900.,  100626.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use [`numpy.core.defchararray.replace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html#numpy.core.defchararray.replace)

```
>>> numpy.core.defchararray.replace(arr, ',','').astype(np.float)

array([4364541., 2330200., 2107648., 1525711., 1485231., 1257500.,
       1098200., 1065106.,  962100.,  920200.,  124204.,  122320.,
        119742.,  116627.,  115900.,  108400.,  108400.,  108000.,
        103795.,  102900.,  101845.,  100900.,  100626.])
```

Or `np.char.replace` as noted in comments by Cold. Naturally, this [package provides is built for arrays of type `numpy.string_` or `numpy.unicode_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.char.html)

If object type,

```
replace(a.astype(np.unicode_), ',','').astype(np.float)
```

Comment: A shorter alias: `np.char.replace` will also do the same thing.

Comment: That won't work if `arr` is `object` dtype.  First have to convert it to a string dtype.  The `char` functions essentially iterate on the elements of a string dtype and apply the corresponding string method.  My guess is the speed will be similar to iterating on a object dtype array.